# Getting syntax error when state params is used to send the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I used state params in my page to send the data from one page to another page, here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Syntax Error: Token ':' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 157 of the expression
```

Please take a look at the code that I have written below :

```
<a ui-sref="EditoldAddress({id:AddressGetData.id,fullName:AddressGetData.companyName,MobileNo:AddressGetData.phoneNo,AternateMob:AddressGetData.alternatePhoneNo,contct1:AddressGetData:contactPersonName,contact2:AddressGetData.secondContactPerson,add1:AddressGetData.addressLine1,add2:AddressGetData.addressLine2,pinCode:AddressGetData.pinCode,landMrk:AddressGetData.landMark,state:AddressGetData.state,serId:AddressGetData.userId,Place:AddressGetData.place})">Edit</a>
```

JS Part :

```
  .state('EditoldAddress', {
        url: '/EditoldAddress/:id/:fullName/:MobileNo/:AternateMob/:contct1/:contact2/:add1/:add2/:pinCode/:landMrk/:state/:UserId/:Place',
        templateUrl: 'Edit-old-address.html',
        controller: 'EditoldController'
    })
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is the worst way of passing parameters to a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After prettifying your `ui-sref` value, it looks like:

```
EditoldAddress({
  id: AddressGetData.id,
  fullName: AddressGetData.companyName,
  MobileNo: AddressGetData.phoneNo,
  AternateMob: AddressGetData.alternatePhoneNo,
  contct1: AddressGetData
  : contactPersonName,
  contact2: AddressGetData.secondContactPerson, 
  add1: AddressGetData.addressLine1, 
  add2: AddressGetData.addressLine2,
  pinCode: AddressGetData.pinCode, 
  landMrk: AddressGetData.landMark, 
  state: AddressGetData.state,
  serId: AddressGetData.userId,
  Place: AddressGetData.place
})
```

The part with `contactPersonName` is broken.